# InfoPath form and header fields

Tags: infopath2010

I have two infoPath forms both share common header fields like Name,Position,Month,Year etc.

How do I create header fields in SharePoint only once when I publish both these forms ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a SharePoint List form, you can only use one InfoPath form. You can use a different view in the form if you want a different presentation of the same data.